# http2 request not working in cloudfront connected by route53 on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, http2

i provide some service with aws.

in my case

S3 react bundle file => cloudfront => route 53

http2 request success in cloudfront

for example, when i access to cloudfront `Domain Name`, i can receive all chunk file and css file with http2. like below picture

[image]

but, when i access to `Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)` in cloud front

all request converted to http1.1

[image]

My `route 53` option like that

RecordType : A - Routes traffic to an IPv4 address and some AWS resources

Routing Policy : Simple routing

i dont know what is problem.

thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

... this problem was our company..

our company pass http2 request using whitelist.

sorry for confuse.